# Use regex to find a string that does not contain \texttt{ but does contain another string

Tags: regex, latex, libreoffice-writer

I have variables in a tex file that should be enclosed in `\texttt{}` but are not. They are typically two words separated by an underscore: `word1_word2`. I can find these variables using regex with `[\w]*\\_[\w]*`. However, I would like to only find instances where these variables are not enclosed by `\texttt{}`, and replace them with `\texttt{[\w]*\\_[\w]}`.

I have spent an hour or so trying to figure out how to do this, but haven't been able to. For instance, `^(\\texttt\{)[\w]*\_[\w]*)` doesn't work.

I'm using Libre Office Writer.

Here's another example:

- find: `?<!(\{.*)\b([:alnum:])+\\_([:alnum:])+\b(?!\})`
- replace: `\\texttt{$0}`

As you can see it shows search key not found, while in the last three `\items` there are instances of `new\_ID`, `new\_code` and `new\_storage` that are not enclosed within `\texttt{}`, while in each of the same `\item` there is another instance of each of these within `\texttt{}`, along with other text. I want it to replace these instances with `\texttt{new\_ID}`, etc. Note the change on the end of each of these lines:

Before:

```
    \item \texttt{Change\_ID(ID, new\_ID):} Changes the ID of the object with the given ID to new\_ID.
    \item \texttt{Change\_code(ID, new\_code):} Changes the code of the object with the given ID to new\_code.
    \item \texttt{Change\_storage(ID, new\_storage):} Changes the storage of the object with the given ID to new\_storage.
```

After:

```
    \item \texttt{Change\_ID(ID, new\_ID):} Changes the ID of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_ID}.
    \item \texttt{Change\_code(ID, new\_code):} Changes the code of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_code}.
    \item \texttt{Change\_storage(ID, new\_storage):} Changes the storage of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_storage}.
```

[image]

Comment: The list of [LibreOffice Regular Expresssions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions) does not contain a negative lookbehind assertion.  However, if you are working with tex files, then why not use an actual text editor such as vim?  For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/99129/5100564.

Comment: I'm planning to use VS Code with texlive and the tex extension soon.

Answer (score 0):

I see what happened, regex have to be anchored.

Here is a working solution except it replace only 1 occurrence per line. If you have some lines with more than 1 occurrence, you have to press <kbd>Replace all</kbd> multiple times.

- Find: `^(.*?)((?<!\{)\b\w+\\_\w+\b(?!\}))`
- Replace: `$1\\texttt{$2}`

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # begining of line
    (.*?)           # group 1, 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    (               # start group 2
        (?<!\{)     # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't "{" before
        \b          # word boundary
        \w+         # 1 or more word characters
        \\_         # an escaped underscore
        \w+         # 1 or more word characters
        \b          # word boundary
        (?!\})      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't "}" after
    )               # end group 2
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that doesn't work when e.g. there is text in between `\texttt{` and `word1\_word2`, it will still find those variables. I have tried `(?<!(\{.*)\b([:alnum:])+\\_([:alnum:])+\b(?!\})`, but that doesn't work. I added `.*` to match zero or more characters between `\{` and `word1\_word2`, and a `\\` to match a backslash.

Comment: @JamesRay: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1426005/edit) and add sample rel text and expedted result. Especially with something that doesn't work with this regex.

Comment: Toto, done as requested.

Comment: @JamesRay: Could you copy/paste example as text instead of image so I can do some tests. Add also expected result.

Comment: OK Toto, I pasted relevant and mentioned text from the screenshot to the question.

Comment: @JamesRay: See my updated answer.

Comment: Toto, sorry, I edited the question incorrectly, and have updated it to what it looked like before and what it looks like now that I've manually edited it.

Comment: @JamesRay: I see, but I think such regex is too complex for libreOffice Writer. If you want I've found a regex that works with Notepad++. Tell me if it is OK for you.  Find: `^((?:.*?)\{.*?\})|(.*?)((?<!\{)\b\w+\\_\w+\b(?!\}))` and Replace with: `(?1$1:$2\\texttt{$3}`

Comment: Toto, just tried with VS Code on Manjaro Linux. This will find all instances of `\b\w+\\_\w+\b`, rather than just the ones that are not enclosed with `\\text{}` so I don't see how it is better than just searching for that and manually replacing it. Before: https://imgur.com/3KCw9GP.png. After replace all: https://imgur.com/73xoxHT.png. I'm just installing `community/notepadqq`, a Notepad++-like text editor for Linux.

Comment: After replace all: `(?1    \item \texttt{Change\_ID(ID, new\_ID):}:\texttt{}(?1: Changes the ID of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_ID}.
(?1    \item \texttt{Change\_code(ID, new\_code):}:\texttt{}(?1: Changes the code of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_code}.
(?1    \item \texttt{Change\_storage(ID, new\_storage):}:\texttt{}(?1: Changes the storage of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_storage}.`

Comment: Notepadqq appears to be way too laggy or freezing, it just freezes when I try replace all. Another app, leafpad, is like Notepad and doesn't support regex.

Answer (score 0):

The needed regex for such job is too complex for LibreOffice writer and for editor like notepadqq or sublimeText.

It works with Notepad++ but as you are Linux user, I suggest you to use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ape 's/^.*?\{.*?\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(.*?)((?<!\{)\b\w+\\_\w+\b(?!\}))/$1\\texttt{$2}/g' file
```

you can use `perl -i.bak -ape ...` if you want to replace the file inplace, the original will be backuped with extension `.back`

**Output:**

```
\item \texttt{Change\_ID(ID, new\_ID):} Changes the ID of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_ID}.
\item \texttt{Change\_code(ID, new\_code):} Changes the code of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_code}.
\item \texttt{Change\_storage(ID, new\_storage):} Changes the storage of the object with the given ID to \texttt{new\_storage}.
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/                  # substitute
  ^                 # begining of line
    .*?\{.*?\}      # 0 or more any character followed by 0 or more character between curly braces
    (*SKIP)(*FAIL)  # if found, forget it
  |                 # OR
    (.*?)           # group 1, 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    (               # start group 2
        (?<!\{)     # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't "{" before
        \b          # word boundary
        \w+         # 1 or more word characters
        \\_         # an escaped underscore
        \w+         # 1 or more word characters
        \b          # word boundary
        (?!\})      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't "}" after
    )               # end group 2
/                   # delimiter, replace with:
    $1              # content of group 1
    \\texttt{$2}    # suround group 2
/g                  # global replacement
```